# Spark window function per time

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have some dataframe with the following structure:

```
ID| Page    |   User          |    Timestamp      |
|1|Page 1   |Ericd            |2002-09-07 19:39:55|
|1|Page 1   |Liir             |2002-10-12 03:01:42|
|1|Page 1   |Tubby            |2002-10-12 03:02:23|
|1|Page 1   |Mojo             |2002-10-12 03:18:24|
|1|Page 1   |Kirf             |2002-10-12 03:19:03|
|2|Page 2   |The Epopt        |2001-11-28 22:27:37|
|2|Page 2   |Conversion script|2002-02-03 01:49:16|
|2|Page 2   |Bryan Derksen    |2002-02-25 16:51:15|
|2|Page 2   |Gear             |2002-10-04 12:46:06|
|2|Page 2   |Tim Starling     |2002-10-06 08:13:42|
|2|Page 2   |Tim Starling     |2002-10-07 03:00:54|
|2|Page 2   |Salsa Shark      |2003-03-18 01:45:32|
```

and I would like to find the number of users which were visited the pages for some time period (per each month for example). For example for 10th month of 2002 the result will be

```
|1|Page 1   |Liir             |2002-10-12 03:01:42| 
|1|Page 1   |Tubby            |2002-10-12 03:02:23|
|1|Page 1   |Mojo             |2002-10-12 03:18:24|
|1|Page 1   |Kirf             |2002-10-12 03:19:03|
|2|Page 2   |Gear             |2002-10-04 12:46:06|
|2|Page 2   |Tim Starling     |2002-10-06 08:13:42|
|2|Page 2   |Tim Starling     |2002-10-07 03:00:54|
```

and the count of pages:

```
              numberOfUsers (in October 2002)
|1|Page 1   |      4
|2|Page 2   |      3
```

The question is also how to apply this logic for the every month for each year. I figured out how to find for example occurences for the last n-days

```
days = lambda i: i * 86400
window = (Window().partitionBy(col("page"))
          .orderBy(col("timestamp").cast("timestamp").cast("long")).rangeBetween(-days(30), 0))

df = df.withColumn("monthly_occurrences", func.count("user").over(window))
df.show()
```

some suggestions I'll appreciate

Comment: Hi metron, did you solve your issue? If so, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) one of the answers to mark your question as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first create column that contains the year-month combination, and then use that column to group by. So a working example would be:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = sc.parallelize([
    ('2018-06-02T00:00:00.000Z','tim', 'page 1' ),
    ('2018-07-20T00:00:00.000Z','tim', 'page 1' ),
    ('2018-07-20T00:00:00.000Z','john', 'page 2' ),
    ('2018-07-20T00:00:00.000Z','john', 'page 2' ),
    ('2018-08-20T00:00:00.000Z','john', 'page 2' )
]).toDF(("datetime","user","page" ))

df = df.withColumn('yearmonth',F.concat(F.year('datetime'),F.lit('-'),F.month('datetime')))    
df_agg = df.groupBy('yearmonth','page').count()
df_agg.show()
```

Output:

```
+---------+------+-----+
|yearmonth|  page|count|
+---------+------+-----+
|   2018-7|page 2|    2|
|   2018-6|page 1|    1|
|   2018-7|page 1|    1|
|   2018-8|page 2|    1|
+---------+------+-----+
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If You are looking for dynamic periods, first convert date to timestamp then substract all timestamps from today and divide (integer) to timestamp of time interval that you want to group. Code below is grouping rows by 5 days intervals.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from datetime import datetime

# todays timestamp
Today = datetime.today().timestamp()
# how many timestamp is today 
DAY_TIMESTAMPS = 24 * 60 * 60

df = sc.parallelize([
    ('2017-06-02 00:00:00','tim', 'page 1' ),
    ('2017-07-20 00:00:00','tim', 'page 1' ),
    ('2017-07-21 00:00:00','john', 'page 2' ),
    ('2017-07-22 00:00:00','john', 'page 2' ),
    ('2017-08-23 00:00:00','john', 'page 2' )
]).toDF(("datetime","user","page" ))

# group by five days
timeInterval = 5* DAY_TIMESTAMPS

df \
    .withColumn('timestamp', F.unix_timestamp(F.to_date('datetime', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))) \ 
    .withColumn('timeIntervalBefore', ((Today-F.col('timestamp'))/(timeInterval)).cast('integer')) \
    .groupBy('timeIntervalBefore', 'page') \
    .agg(F.count('user').alias('number of users')).show()
```

Results:

```
+------------------+------+---------------+
|timeIntervalBefore|  page|number of users|
+------------------+------+---------------+
|                70|page 2|              2|
|                80|page 1|              1|
|                70|page 1|              1|
|                64|page 2|              1|
+------------------+------+---------------+
```

If you need to approximate dates of periods time :

```
df \
    .withColumn('timestamp', F.unix_timestamp(F.to_date('datetime', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))) \
    .withColumn('timeIntervalBefore', ((Today-F.col('timestamp'))/(timeInterval)).cast('integer')) \
    .groupBy('timeIntervalBefore', 'page') \
    .agg(
        F.count('user').alias('number_of_users'), 
        F.min('timestamp').alias('FirstDay'), 
        F.max('timestamp').alias('LastDay')) \
    .select(
        'page', 
        'number_of_users', 
        F.from_unixtime('firstday').alias('firstDay'), 
        F.from_unixtime('firstday').alias('lastDay')).show()
```

Results:

```
+------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|  page|number_of_users|           firstDay|            lastDay|
+------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|page 2|              2|2017-07-21 00:00:00|2017-07-21 00:00:00|
|page 1|              1|2017-06-02 00:00:00|2017-06-02 00:00:00|
|page 1|              1|2017-07-20 00:00:00|2017-07-20 00:00:00|
|page 2|              1|2017-08-23 00:00:00|2017-08-23 00:00:00|
+------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```